# Cannot update child record when Delete rule is NO ACTION

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

In ORACLE database, I tried to update a record `ENTITY_ID` in a table `TICKETS`. I got the following error message:
`SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TICKET_U01) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.`

However, when I checked I found the `DELETE RULE` in this table is `NO ACTION` among the constraints. The record `ENTITY_ID` is a FK referenced to the table `ENTITY`. My question is, is not `NO ACTION` rule applied to the parent record in this case, I mean I should get this error when I try to update the record from the table `ENTITY` rather than the table `TICKETS`. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Do you have a unique constraint on `tickets.entity_id`?

Comment: @Rachcha No, the entity_id can be duplicated in `tickets` table